# How to use jquery to autocomplete with usernames for a message app?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, jquery-ui

I'm playing around with a little message box and am trying to have an autofill feature with jquery UI but it's not working. Nothing autofills. here's what I've got so far...

**composemessage.php**

```
<script> 

$(function() {
$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
    source: "usersarray.php",
    dataType:'json',
    minLength: 0,
    delay:0

});

$( "#tags" ).click(function() {
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete("search","");
});
});
</script>
```

**usersarray.php**

```
$id = $_SESSION['account_id'];

$getmsg = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE account_id = $id";      
$showmsg = @mysqli_query ($dbc, $getmsg);
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($showmsg, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

$arrResults = array($row['user_username']);


} // END WHILE


// Print them out, one per line
echo json_encode($arrResults);
```

Comment: @user is it making the ajax request?  Have you tried navigating to your usersarray.php directly to see if it's actually printing the usernames you expect?

Comment: I have - and the problem lays in how I'm getting that array because it's not printing out the array at all.

Comment: And yes, the ajax request is functional when I manually enter an array not from a mysql query

Comment: if autocompletes works when using array instead of db query in php file, try debugging your php code.

Comment: thanks - any suggestions as to how to do that?

Comment: You're selecting from the user table where the account id is the same as the account id of the logged in user? Have you checked that this query actually works, and that `$arrResults` contains anything at all?

Comment: Yes, the account id is valid and works has data in it.

Answer (score 0):

JSON results should look something like this:

```
users = ['user1', 'user2'];
```

Based on your jquery request, you're expecting something in that format.  Can you show us what is output from your usersarray.php file?  Don't forget to mask the usernames if those are important to you.

Comment: scratch that - sorry it says "null"

Comment: Then I guess at this point you need to get your query working.  Instead of `SELECT * ...`, use `SELECT username ...`.  It is preferred to be more explicit when selecting field names.  Verify there are records in that table on the database.  Make sure your call to `$row['fieldName']` is the same as the `SELECT fieldName`...whatever it may be.  Start there, I guess.

Comment: Also print your `$id` and make sure you have an expected value there.

Answer (score 0):

Json have to be in this format:

```
 [{label: 'label1', value: 'value1'},{label: 'label2', value: 'value2'},{label: 'label3', value: 'value3'}];
```

The javascrip part:

```
$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
    source: function( request, response ) {
        var term = request.term;

         $.ajax({
            url: "username.php",
            dataType: 'json',
            async: true,
            data: request,
            timeout: 3000,
            success: function(data,status,xhr){ 
                response( data );
            }
        });

    },
    delay: 100,
    minLength: 0
});
```

The HTML

```
<input name="username" class="detailedViewTextBox suggest_hidden" id="tags" autocomplete='off' value="" type="text" size="18">
```

Comment: Okay - so how do I format my PHP/mysql query to get it into that json format?

Comment: I choose this way to call ajax for the possibility to setup the async way and the timeout.

Comment: Your query can be like this, then the associative array make the job:
$sql="select username as value, username as label from user where username like '$term%' limit 10"