# How to format a Mysql/php array for json?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

Asked this before, but I've narrowed down the issue to this bit of code. Here's my code, when I run it, it just says "null"..

```
$getmsg = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE account_id = $id";      
$showmsg = @mysqli_query ($dbc, $getmsg);
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($showmsg, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

$arrResults = array($row['user_username']);


} // END WHILE


// Print them out, one per line
echo json_encode($arrResults);
```

Comment: I think I found your previously abandoned question here where we narrowed it down: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5902397/how-to-use-jquery-to-autocomplete-with-usernames-for-a-message-app/5902648  That's shady.

Answer (score 4):

First of all you have put the echo outside the loop which just echoes the last item instead of everyone and you don't check if there is a error with your query.

Instead this would be sufficient:

```
$getmsg = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE account_id = $id";      
$result = @mysqli_query($dbc, $getmsg) or die("Error: " . mysql_error());
$result = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
echo json_encode($result);
```

It puts the result in one assoc array and then converts the whole array to json and prints it.

Comment: Not related to author's problem, but using `@` is a bad style, as well as outputting `mysql_error()` and mixing MySQLi (`mysqli_query()`) with MySQL (`mysql_error()`).

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are likely having is in your assignment statement:

$arrResults = array($row['user_username']);

You should change it to the following:

$arrResults[] = $row['user_username'];